# PHPMailer won't send html message

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have problems with sending html based message with php mailer. Some answers here in stackoverflow says to include $mail->isHTML(true) which i do but no result.. here is the code

```
require '...';      
$mail = new PHPMailer;        
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = '...';  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = '...'; 
$mail->Password = '...';                              
$mail->setFrom("....");
$mail->addAddress("...");                 
$mail->Subject = "...";
$mail->Body    = "<li>abcd</li>";
$mail->isHTML(true); 
if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `<li>abcd</li>` isn't enough. You need to use `<!DOCTYPE html><head></head><body>...</body></html>` as proper HTML markup.

Comment: oo, ok. I did not know that some examples did not refer to that. i will try it end post reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<li>abcd</li>` isn't enough and `<ul></ul>` tags should also be included. You need to use `<!DOCTYPE html><head></head><body>...</body></html>` as proper and full HTML markup and concatenating `$mail->Body`.

```
$mail->Body     = "<!DOCTYPE html>"; // the first one does not contain the dot
$mail->Body    .= "<head></head>";
$mail->Body    .= "<title></title>";
$mail->Body    .= "<body>";
$mail->Body    .= "<ul>";
$mail->Body    .= "<li>abcd</li>";
$mail->Body    .= "</ul>";
$mail->Body    .= "</body>";
$mail->Body    .= "</html>";
```

You can also substitute `<ul></ul>` for `<ol></ol>` depending on the type you want to use.

Comment: Hey fred. Do you know what might be the reason that now that i am senind html message g mail do not show the message unless i press this icon '...' that gmail has in the message. The icon has 'hidden title' content is truncated

Comment: @IraklisBekiaris that's normal and could be of 1 of 2 reasons. 1) the message is too long, or you have a 2nd message of the same.

Comment: You forgot the opening <html> tag